# Get mouse position when focus/blur events are fired?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mouse, jquery-events

I'm using jQuery to capture an event:

```
$('input').focus(function(e){

    console.log( e.pageX, e.pageY );

});
```

This doesn't seem to work... any ideas on alternative ways to getting the mouse position?

---

Help would be great.

Comment: I think you can only get the mouse coordinates on events that use the mouse -- click, dblclick, etc. It would be meaningless to get the mouse coordinates if a user focuses on your input by tabbing with the keyboard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only get mouse coordinates using mouse events. If you want to capture the position of the mouse, you can use a global `mousemove` event listener, and store the coordinates in a set of variables, which can later be accessed by the `focus` function. Example:

```
var pageX, pageY; //Declare these globally
$(window).mousemove(function(e){
    pagex = e.pageX;
    pageY = e.pageY;
});

$('input').focus(function(){
    console.log(pageX, pageY); // These variables have been defined by the global
                               //  mousemove event
});
```

Comment: This is the only way to do it, afaik

Comment: Did they mean any [mouse] event here?? ".pageX and .pageY can be read off of any event, not just .mousemove().

For example, perhaps you want to know exactly where a user clicked inside a particular div:

Here's an example where we listen for a click event inside a particular div called #special." http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position

Comment: @jbabey A click is a mouse event. `focus` is not a mouse event.

Comment: @RobW right I understand and I agree with you - it's just strange that the site I linked above says "any event" instead of "any mouse event"

Comment: @Andy I originally wanted to use `x` and `y` too. Then, I thought "It is very likely that x or y are already defined within a function, causing conflicts." Hence, I decided to use the descriptive yet compact `pageX` and `pageY` variable names.

Comment: @RobW I'm notorious among my coworkers for my descriptive variable names :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to get the position relative to the element, try something like this instead:

```
$("input").focus(function(e){
    var relativeX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var relativeY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
});
```