# Position of string at mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I'm trying to find a position in a string to append an `<img>` tag to on drop using jQuery.

What I'm planning on doing is on hover convert the HTML of a paragraph to string, or maybe a text area.

Is there a way to append HTML to the cursor's position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window.getSelection() and Range :

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html

http://help.dottoro.com/ljvhnwsk.php

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks!  This lead me down the road I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

If the X and Y coordinates are given, you can get the element by using `document.elementFromPoint(x, y)`. Otherwise, you can get the X and Y by using the method as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984725/get-mouse-position-when-focus-blur-events-are-fired-javascript-jquery/7984782#7984782).

So, let X and Y be given. Then:

```
function appendElementAt(img, x, y){
    var elem = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
    var pos = elem.getBoundingClientRect();   //Calculate position of element
    var topPos = y - pos.top;                 // Calculate top position
    var leftPos = x - pos.left                // Calculate left positon

    elem.style.position = "relative";
    img.style.position = "absolute";
    img.style.top = topPos;
    img.style.left = leftPos;
    elem.appendChild(img);
}
// Usage:

var img = document.createElement("img");
appendElementAt(img, x, y);
```

Comment: If you were looking to get the exact position of a certain text in an input field, I have previously spent hours on creating that, see: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930578/get-cursor-or-text-position-in-pixels-for-input-element#7948715)

Comment: Great guys, I can't wait to try these later :)