# Obtaining event.PageX equivalent where there's no real event

Tags: jquery, events

I'm displaying the *datePicker* when hovering over an image. The code to fire the event is as follows.

```
$("#calendar").on("mouseover", function (event) {
  $("#calendar").datepicker("dialog", null, function (date) {
    $("#departureDate").val(date);
  }, options, [event.PageX, event.PageY]);
});
```

This works as supposed to, because the event *mouseover* has coordinates where it occurs. Now, I'd also like to fire the event when focusing on an input box, so I added the following code, noticing that the *datePicker* isn't displayed because the event is *null*. When I enter [0, 0] as coordinates, I get it to show but in the wrong location.

```
$("#departureDate").on("focus", function (event) {
  $("#calendar").datepicker("dialog", null, function (date) {
    $("#departureDate").val(date);
  //}, options, [event.PageX, event.PageY]);
  }, options, [0, 0]);
});
```

How can I obtain the coordinates of the control that is being focused on?
Or even wider - how can I obtain the coordinates of a control that has caused **any** event?

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting it, but are you really just looking for the top and left offset of the input. As a sidenote, what is wrong with the way the datepicker positions itself by default ?

Comment: #1: Yes, I'm looking for the position of e.g. input box that gains the focus to display the datePicker at. How can I get to where it's placed on the page pixel-wise? #2 I'm getting the datePicker in the middle of my screen . And I wish to control where it's put. Perhaps there's a smarter way to approach it?

Comment: You don't need the mouse position to get the position of the input, just do `$(this).offset()` to get the elements offset ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `offset()` or `position()` for that

```
$("#departureDate").on("focus", function (event) {
    var offset = $(this).offset(); // or .position() 
    $("#calendar").datepicker("dialog", null, function (date) {
        $("#departureDate").val(date);
    }, options, [offset.top, offset.left]);
});
```

---

[**.offset()**](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

> Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched
>   elements, **relative to the document**.

---

[**.position()**](http://api.jquery.com/position/)

> Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, **relative to the offset parent**.

Note that there is a difference, one gets the coordinates relative to the parent, and one gets the coordinates relative to the document.

Comment: Hmm... There seems not to be any *offset()* - it's *undefined*... Maybe it's because I lied before? It's *$("#departureDate").on("focus", function (event) { executeCalendar(event); });* and in the function I do the magic. Is the reference to *$(this)* wrong then?

Comment: I went *event.target.offsetLeft + 270,event.target.offsetTop]* and now it does what's supposed to. I'm guessing 270 is the width of the picker, so I can put in that, instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984725/get-mouse-position-when-focus-blur-events-are-fired-javascript-jquery) has the solution. Overall you have to declare global variables(or an object) that are updated whenever the mouse moves. Then access them when the event you desire fires.

```
You can only get mouse coordinates using mouse events. If you want to capture the position of the mouse, you can use a global mousemove event listener, and store the coordinates in a set of variables, which can later be accessed by the focus function. Example:

var pageX, pageY; //Declare these globally
$(window).mousemove(function(e){
    pagex = e.pageX;
    pageY = e.pageY;
});

$('input').focus(function(){
    console.log(pageX, pageY); // These variables have been defined by the global
                               //  mousemove event
});
```

Comment: Good try but no go. This only refers to **where the mouse is**. A component can gain focus by e.g. tabification or programmatically. I need the coordinates to **where the component is**, not the mouse.